# Vs code not showing the widget end comment in flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am just starting out with flutter and normally when we code in flutter it shows a virtual comment text in vscode after every widget end. But now I cant see it anymore. I dont know what I did to get it away

```
void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));//MaterialApp(These helper comments are missing now)
```

Now its showing without the virtual comments

```
void main() =>
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));
```

Comment: These are missing for me now also. Were you able to get them back?

Answer (score 7):

Go to setting in VS Code and search for ***dart closing labels***. Just enable the option.